# How to retain original trendline from ggplot in ggplotly R and add gridlines dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, trendline, gridlines

I Have the following dataframe in R

```
  A<-data.frame("Col1"= c(21.5 ,22.5 ,15.5, 20.5 ,17.5 ,14.5 ,23.5, 11.5, 16.5, 25.5 ,18.5, 24.5 ,10.5 , 9.5, 19.5, 26.5, 13.5, 12.5 ,27.5,  4.5 , 5.5,  8.5,  6.5,  7.5))
  A$Col2=c(0.619219548, 0.723265668,0.122833055, 0.536849680, 0.257225692 ,0.081648474, 0.794797325 ,0.023125359, 0.194364553, 0.909681117, 0.343930779, 0.857658382, 0.018791029 ,0.014457257,   0.467485576 ,0.950865217, 0.062140165, 0.040464671, 0.989875246, 0.001502443,0.003637989 ,0.012290763, 0.005796326, 0.007959621)
```

I am trying to create a chart in with logscales using ggplot and plotly

```
library(ggplot)
library(plotly)

plott1<- ggplot(A, aes(x=Col1, y=Col2)) + geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method = "lm")     +scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1,max(A$Col1) , 1))+scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0,1,0.1))+theme( panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "green", size = 0.5), panel.grid.minor= element_line(colour = "green", size = 0.2))

B<-ggplotly(plott1, dynamicTicks = TRUE, originalData = T )%>%layout(B, yaxis = list(type = "log"),xaxis = list(type = "log"))
```

I am unable to retain the trendline generated in plott1 in B(y The trendline gets curved) and the gridlines vanish. I request someone to guide me as I am unable to solve this issue. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linear trend line gets curved because you switch to log scales when converting the ggplot to a plotly object. Hence, to solve your issue I would suggest to do the log transformation in ggplot:

```
library(plotly)

ggplot(A, aes(x=Col1, y=Col2)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")     +
  scale_x_log10(minor_breaks = seq(1,max(A$Col1) , 1))+
  scale_y_log10(minor_breaks = seq(0,1,0.1))+
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "green", size = 0.5), panel.grid.minor= element_line(colour = "green", size = 0.2))
```

[image]

```
ggplotly(originalData = T)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. The change in gridlines is also due to similar reasons I suppose